# Android How to register OnTouchEvent for entire Activity main content view?

Tags: android, android-activity, touch

I have implemented onTouchEvent(TouchEvent) on my activity.  However, I would like to know what steps are required to register this as the event for the activities main Content view.  I want to set the onTouchEvent for the view that covers the entire screen space of the activity.  there is a setContentView() which takes a layout id.  How do I register the activity as the ontouchEvent listener to the main content view.  I am considering findByView(activityLayoutId) to get this view, but this does not seem quite like the right or best way.  Thanks

Comment: or is it enough just to implement the View.onTouchEvent in the activity and the view will auto register with this?

Comment: I am just looking for how to activite touch event on whole activity screen, not on some view added to this screen.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you're looking for a way to get your content view as a View after `Activity#setContentView(int)`, then you can set an id on the outer-most element of your layout:

```
android:id="@+id/entire_view"
```

and reference it in your `onCreate` method after `setContentView`:

```
View view = getViewById(R.id.entire_view);
view.setOnTouchListener( ...
```

Comment: @Androider  "**_I am just looking for how to activite touch event on whole activity screen, not on some view added to this screen._**" then why you accepted this answer?! this is still some view added to this activity.

Comment: Also make sure that the view is "clickable", if it is not that by default, you can simpy set the view to be "clickable" by setting android:clickable="true" on the view in the XML-file.

Answer (score 3):

Like this (in `onCreate`):

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

View view = findViewById(R.id.main); 
view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public boolean onTouch(View view,MotionEvent event) {


                                        return true;

                                    }
                                });
```

Answer (score 1):

Activities `onCreate()` method:

```
onCreate(){
  setContentView(R.id.yourMainLayout);
  View contentView = (View)findViewById(R.id.yourMainLayout);
  contentView.setOnTouchListener((View.OnTouchListener)this);
 }
```

Unless someone knows a better way.

Comment: you might still use R.layout.yourMainLayout  and within layout provide youMainLayout as id