# Android: detect when touching event finished

Tags: android, kotlin

I am using viewpager2 in my application. I enabled auto slide using rxjava2 (observable interval). I want to stop auto slide when user touch the viewpager and after touch finishes start auto slide. But I can not find proper way to detect touch finish event. I tried action_up, but it triggers only when fast touch like click. It's not detect when user touch 2 second and finish touch.

```
Observable.interval(SLIDER_DELAY, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe {
                if (!homeAdapter.touchStatus()) {
                    if (viewPagerSlider.currentItem < homeAdapter.itemCount - 1) {
                        viewPagerSlider.setCurrentItem(
                            viewPagerSlider.currentItem + 1,
                            true
                        )
                    } else {
                        viewPagerSlider.setCurrentItem(0, true)
                    }
                }
            }
```

HomeAdapter

```
itemView.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
                when (event.action) {
                    MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> isTouched = true
                    MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> isTouched = false
                    else -> {}
                }
                true
            }

fun touchStatus() = this.isTouched
```

How can I detect when user finished touch event after some time?

Comment: The event should trigger if it happens on the `itemView`. Are you moving the `itemView`? Maybe you can register the touch listener on a parent view

Comment: I tried to put listener to viewpager, but it is not worked

Comment: Maybe this will help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/5279261/2232127

Comment: @JensV This is not helps